# MYSQL connection refused while using docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have started using Docker since yesterday but I cant figure out to fix the mysql connection refused error. I was wondering if any of you guys could help me as I don't know wat to do hahah

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASENAME: my_test_database
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_USER: develop
      MYSQL_PASSWRD: develop
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  www:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: php:8.0.30-apache
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
```

and this is inside my dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0.30-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

hope anyone could help me thanks!

I was expecting a connection with my database server

EDIT: changed `PWA` to `PMA`

Comment: The env vars for your `phpmyadmin` container should start with `PMA_`, not `PWA_`. And you probably want `PMA_HOST=db`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
environment:
      - PWA_HOST=localhost
```

Here `localhost` refers to IP-address of the `phpmyadmin` service's container, and not to your machine's IP. To make other services communicate to `db` service you have to provide `db` service's name wherever you would provide IP-address of the machine running `mysql`.

Also note, that you mistyped the name of the environment variable(should be `PMA_HOST` according to phpMyAdmin docker image [page](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/))

So, the correct configuration would be:

```
environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information but sadly this did not work
this is what i know hve 
```yml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  www:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: php:8.0.30-apache
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
     - PMA_HOST=db
     - PMA_PORT=3306
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
``` docker file hasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues in your docker-compose.yml.

`db` service

- `MYSQL_DATABASENAME` should be `MYSQL_DATABASE`
- `MYSQL_PASSWRD` should be `MYSQL_PASSWORD`
- Avoid `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable as it causes issues with this image ([see docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql#:%7E:text=especially%20variables%20like%20MYSQL_HOST))
- `MYSQL_PORT` is unnecessary, as you are setting it to the default port (not even sure this env var is used)

`phpmyadmin` service

- You need to map the port for PMA `8080:80` - will make PMA available at `http://localhost:8080` on host.
- `PMA_PORT` is unnecessary, as 3306 is the default.

Your dockerfile is not being used by anything as the `www` service is using `image`, not `build` ([read this example in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/))

It's a good idea to set a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_test_database
      MYSQL_USER: develop
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: develop
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  www:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: php:8.0.30-apache
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
```

If you want to use your `Dockerfile` for your `www` service, change it to (assuming `Dockerfile` is in project root):

```yaml
  www:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

[Docs: Compose Build Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/)